# why during exporting access report file to snapshot format. laptop returns there is no enough memory to complete action using access in widows 10?

Tags: memory, microsoft-access, snapshot, viewer

I tried stopping all startup programs, expanding the size of C: drive, I tried many versions of snapshot viewer, and increasing the size of the pagefile. nothing worked.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.